# Text and lines in pycairo

Tags: python, pygtk, pycairo

I'm having a little bit of trouble with pycairo. I want to draw a [chord chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_chart), but for some reason I don't quite understand it only displays the text, not the lines it should be drawing.

I use pygtk (3.0) and pycairo. [Here's the result of what this code draws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng5bD.png)

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    def gen_chart(self, wid, cr):

            x = 10
            y = 60

            cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
            cr.set_line_width(1)
            cr.select_font_face("Open Sans", cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
            cr.set_font_size(40)

            cr.move_to(x, y)
            cr.line_to(x, y)

            counter = 1
            for measure in chord_list: # The list is declared earlier in the source                    
                    x += 10
                    for chord in measure:
                            cr.move_to(x, y)
                            cr.show_text(chord)
                            x += 100
                    if counter % 4 == 0 or counter == 4:
                            x = 10
                            y += 60
                            cr.move_to(x, y)
                            cr.line_to(x, y)
                            counter += 1
                    counter += 1

            cr.move_to(x, y + 10)
            cr.move_to(x, y + 10)
            cr.stroke()
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Ok, so I'm replying myself in case someone runs through the same. I was asking cairo to draw a line in the same point, so it drew nothing. The line_to under each move_to should move the y axis the desired amount of pixels.

Comment: Instead of a comment to your self it's ok to create an answer and mark it correct. As well as including the corrected code in the answer with an image of the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is that it "draws" a line to the same coordinate, so it becomes a point which has no 2d properties, and that's why it doesn't draw anything. The corrected code:

```
def gen_chart(self, wid, cr):

    x = 10
    y = 60

    cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
    cr.set_line_width(1)
    cr.select_font_face("Open Sans", cairo.FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, cairo.FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL)
    cr.set_font_size(40)

    cr.move_to(x, y)
    cr.line_to(x, y)

    counter = 1
    for measure in chord_list:                   
        x += 10
        for chord in measure:
            cr.move_to(x, y)
            cr.show_text(chord)
            x += 100
        if counter % 4 == 0 or counter == 4:
            x = 10
            y += 60
            cr.move_to(x, y)
            cr.line_to(x, y + 10)
        counter += 1
    counter += 1

cr.move_to(x, y + 80)
cr.stroke()
```